# Relation between condition number and perturbed matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, error-propagation

Prove that if $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$ and $(A+\delta{}A)(\vec{x}+\delta\vec{x}) = \vec{b}$, then $\dfrac{\|\delta\vec{x}\|/\|\vec{x}+\delta\vec{x}\|}{\|\delta{}A\|/\|A\|} \le \kappa{(A)}$, where $\kappa{(A)} = \|A\|\cdot\|A^{-1}\|$ is the condition number of the matrix $A$.

Attempt at a solution:
$$A\delta\vec{x} + \delta{}A(\vec{x} + \delta\vec{x}) = 0 \Rightarrow \|A\delta\vec{x} + \delta{}A(\vec{x} + \delta\vec{x})\| = 0$$
$$\Rightarrow \|A\delta\vec{x}\| + \|\delta{}A(\vec{x} + \delta\vec{x})\| \ge 0$$
$$\Rightarrow \|A\|\cdot\|\delta\vec{x}\| + \|\delta{}A\|\cdot\|(\vec{x} + \delta\vec{x})\| \ge 0$$
$$\Rightarrow 1 + \frac{\|\delta{}A\|/\|A\|}{\|\delta\vec{x}\|/\|\vec{x}+\delta\vec{x}\|} \ge 0 \quad\quad\text{(dividing by }\|A\|\cdot\|\delta\vec{x}\|)$$
or
$$\Rightarrow 1 + \frac{|\|\delta\vec{x}\|/\|\vec{x}+\delta\vec{x}|\|}{|\|\delta{}A\|/\|A\|} \ge 0 \quad\quad\text{(dividing by }\|\delta{}A\|\cdot\|(\vec{x} + \delta\vec{x})\|)$$
This is what I've got so far, and I'm not sure how to bring $\kappa{}(A)$ into the equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relation
$$
(A+\delta A)(x+\delta x)=b,
$$
implies that
$$
Ax+\delta A (x+\delta x)+A\delta x=b,
$$
and since $Ax=b$, the above becomes
$$
\delta A (x+\delta x)+A\delta x=0,
$$
and hence
$$
\delta x= -A^{-1}\delta A (x+\delta x),
$$
which implies that
$$
\|\delta x\|\le \|A^{-1}\|\|\delta A\|\|x+\delta x\|=\kappa(A)\cdot\frac{\|\delta A\|}{\|A\|}\|x+\delta x\|,
$$
and finally
$$
\frac{\frac{\|\delta x\|}{\|x+\delta x\|}}{\frac{\|\delta A\|}{\|A\|}}\le \kappa(A).
$$

Note. This error estimate is known as *backward error analysis* and it is due to [J.H. Wilkinson.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_H._Wilkinson)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Just a minor note - the inequality required contains $\vec{x}+\delta\vec{x}$ and not just $\vec{x}$. So putting $\delta\vec{x} = -A^{-1}\delta{}A(\vec{x}+\delta\vec{x})$ and proceeding with your derivation yields the required inequality.

Comment: @R.K.: Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

This is not quite an answer, but perhaps complements Yiorgos' approach.

The idea is to view $x$ as a function of $A$ and compute the derivative. The implicit function theorem provides a convenient way of computing the derivative.

Let $\phi(y,A) = Ay-b$, we have ${\partial \phi(y,A) \over \partial y} = A$, and 
${\partial \phi(y,A) \over \partial A}(\Delta) = \Delta y$, hence the implicit function theorem give the existence of a locally defined $x$ that satisfies
$A x(A) = b$, and
${\partial x(A) \over \partial A}(\Delta) = ({\partial \phi(y,A) \over \partial y})^{-1} {\partial \phi(y,A) \over \partial A}(\Delta) = A^{-1} \Delta x(A)$.

This gives $\|{\partial x(A) \over \partial A}(\Delta)\| \le \|A^{-1}\| \|\Delta\| \|x(A)\|$. Dividing by ${\|\Delta\| \over \|A\|} \|x(A)\| $ gives
${\left({\|{\partial x(A) \over \partial A}(\Delta)\| \over \|x(A)\|} \right) \over \left( { \|\Delta\| \over \|A\| } \right) } \le \kappa(A)$.